# Capture image through Sencha Application 2.1 without using Phonegap

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to capture a photo from my SenchaTouch 2.1 application and want to display on the view.
I don't want to use Phone Gap just  want to access the camera through my Sencha Application. Kindly share some code that will suffice the above mentioned need Or some suggestions it will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Sencha Touch API docs, for the Ext.device.Camera class?

- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera

Comment: Yes i have looked that,I have used itemId in the view which has the TakePhoto Button,then in the controller i have built one TakePhoto function there i have used this function Ext.device.Camera.              Thanks

Comment: onTakePhotoTap : function() {
Ext.device.Camera.capture({
              source: 'camera',
              success: function(image) {
                  imageView.setSrc(image);
              },
              quality: 75,
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              destination: 'data',
              failure: function() {
Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'There was an error when acquiring the picture.');  },scope: this });
  },                                                     Is it the correct way of using it......

Comment: One more thing how can i test this code weather it is working fine or not..on browser i have checked that it is going inside the succcess function on tapping the button.Kindly let me the ways to test it on device or emulator?..What are the steps for packaging the sencha2.1 app and to import it on device..?

Comment: That looks correct to me.

However, asking how to test this goes a bit outside the scope of your original question. Have you tried using any of the native simulators?

And asking for the steps to package a Sencha Touch app and import it onto a device is WAY too large a topic to just throw in at the end. There's a ton of resources online about that - just Google it!